# Compiling OpenCV with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opencv, centos5

I am trying to compile opencv 2.4.6.1 on Centos 5.10. However, whenever I add WITH_OPENGL=ON, I am unable to compile it.

My cmake line:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/opencv-2.4.6.1-test -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/bin/g++ -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/bin/gcc -D BUILD_opencv_python=OFF -D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-5.5/ -D WITH_FFMPEG=YES -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS=/opt/intel.2013.0.028/tbb/include/ -D TBB_LIB_DIR=/opt/intel.2013.0.028/tbb/lib/intel64/ -D WITH_IPP=ON -D ENABLE_PROFILING=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON  ..
```

I also have the following environment variables set:

```
export IPPROOT=/opt/intel.2013.0.028/ipp/
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/ffmpeg-2.0.2/lib/pkgconfig
```

This results in:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 48 (408)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PG_G
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PG_G - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PG_G
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PG_G - Failed
-- Looking for alloca.h
-- Looking for alloca.h - found
-- Looking for alloca
-- Looking for alloca - not found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Found ZLIB: /lib64/libz.so (found version "1.2.3")
-- Found TIFF: /usr/lib64/libtiff.so 
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so 
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing:  JASPER_LIBRARY JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib64/libpng.so 
-- Looking for /usr/include/png.h
-- Looking for /usr/include/png.h - found
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h - not found
-- Looking for semaphore.h
-- Looking for semaphore.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA - Success
-- checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
--   found gtk+-2.0, version 2.10.4
-- checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
--   found gthread-2.0, version 2.12.3
-- checking for module 'gtkglext-1.0'
--   found gtkglext-1.0, version 1.0.6
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib64/libX11.so;/usr/lib64/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib64/libX11.so;/usr/lib64/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib64/libX11.so
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   package 'libdc1394-2' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394'
--   package 'libdc1394' not found
-- checking for module 'libv4l1'
--   package 'libv4l1' not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   found libavcodec, version 55.18.102
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
--   found libavformat, version 55.12.100
-- checking for module 'libavutil'
--   found libavutil, version 52.38.100
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   found libswscale, version 2.3.100
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - not found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- checking for module 'tbb'
--   package 'tbb' not found
-- found IPP: 7.1.1 [7.1.1]
-- at: /opt/intel.2013.0.028/ipp
-- IPP libs: libippvm_l.a;libippcc_l.a;libippcv_l.a;libippi_l.a;libipps_l.a;libippcore_l.a
-- IPP libs: libippvm_l.a;libippcc_l.a;libippcv_l.a;libippi_l.a;libipps_l.a;libippcore_l.a
-- CUDA detected: 5.5
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_11,code=sm_11;-gencode;arch=compute_12,code=sm_12;-gencode;arch=compute_13,code=sm_13;-gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_20;-gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_21;-gencode;arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;-gencode;arch=compute_20,code=compute_20;-gencode;arch=compute_30,code=compute_30
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python (found suitable version "2.6.4", required is "2.0")
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.a (Required is at least version "2.6.4")
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- Could NOT find OPENCL (missing:  OPENCL_LIBRARY OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.6.1 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 2.6.18-308.11.1.el5 x86_64
--     CMake:                       2.8.6
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/gmake
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/bin/g++  (ver 4.8.1)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -ggdb3
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/bin/gcc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -ggdb3
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core imgproc flann highgui features2d calib3d ml video objdetect contrib photo legacy gpu nonfree stitching superres ts videostab
--     Disabled:                    python world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera java ocl
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.10.4)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.12.3)
--     GtkGlExt:                    YES (ver 1.0.6)
--     OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib64/libGLU.so /usr/lib64/libGL.so /usr/lib64/libSM.so /usr/lib64/libICE.so /usr/lib64/libX11.so /usr/lib64/libXext.so)
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.3)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so (ver 62)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib64/libpng.so (ver 1.2.10)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib64/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 3.8.2)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 55.18.102)
--       format:                    YES (ver 55.12.100)
--       util:                      YES (ver 52.38.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 2.3.100)
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/NO
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     7.1.1 [7.1.1]
--          at:                     /opt/intel.2013.0.028/ipp
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use TBB:                     YES (ver 4.1 interface 6101)
--     Use OpenMP:                  NO
--     Use GCD                      NO
--     Use Concurrency              NO
--     Use C=:                      NO
--     Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 5.5)
--     Use OpenCL:                  NO
-- 
--   NVIDIA CUDA
--     Use CUFFT:                   YES
--     Use CUBLAS:                  NO
--     USE NVCUVID:                 NO
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             11 12 13 20 21 30
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:            20 30
--     Use fast math:               NO
-- 
--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/local/bin/python (ver 2.6.4)
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Build Documentation:         NO
--     Sphinx:                      NO
--     PdfLaTeX compiler:           /usr/bin/pdflatex
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local/opencv-2.4.6.1-test
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /usr/local/src/opencv-2.4.6.1/release
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /usr/local/src/opencv-2.4.6.1/release
```

This is the error I get when I try to build it:

```
Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/copy.cpp.o
/usr/local/src/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gl_core_3_1.cpp: In function ‘void* IntGetProcAddress(const char*)’:
/usr/local/src/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gl_core_3_1.cpp:131:88: error: ‘glXGetProcAddressARB’ was not declared in this scope
         #define CV_GL_GET_PROC_ADDRESS(name) glXGetProcAddressARB((const GLubyte*) name)
                                                                                        ^
/usr/local/src/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gl_core_3_1.cpp:136:31: note: in expansion of macro ‘CV_GL_GET_PROC_ADDRESS’
         void* func =  (void*) CV_GL_GET_PROC_ADDRESS(name);
                               ^
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/gl_core_3_1.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Here is the results of rpm -qa | grep gl

```
libglade2-2.6.0-2
glade2-2.12.1-6.el5
freeglut-devel-2.4.0-7.1.el5
dbus-glib-0.73-11.el5_9
glx-utils-6.5.1-7.11.el5_9
glib-1.2.10-20.el5
dbus-glib-0.73-11.el5_9
glibc-devel-2.5-118.el5_10.2
gtkglext-devel-1.0.6-1.el5.rf
glibc-common-2.5-118.el5_10.2
glib-devel-1.2.10-20.el5
NetworkManager-glib-0.7.0-13.el5
xscreensaver-gl-extras-5.04-1.el5.centos
libglade2-devel-2.6.0-2
glibc-devel-2.5-118.el5_10.2
gtkglext-1.0.6-1.el5.rf
compat-glibc-headers-2.3.4-2.26
compat-glibc-2.3.4-2.26
freeglut-2.4.0-7.1.el5
glib-devel-1.2.10-20.el5
NetworkManager-glib-0.7.0-13.el5
glib2-devel-2.12.3-4.el5_3.1
glibc-2.5-118.el5_10.2
xscreensaver-gl-base-5.04-1.el5.centos
gtkglext-devel-1.0.6-1.el5.rf
avahi-glib-0.6.16-10.el5_6
glib2-2.12.3-4.el5_3.1
glib2-devel-2.12.3-4.el5_3.1
libglade2-devel-2.6.0-2
freeglut-devel-2.4.0-7.1.el5
glibc-2.5-118.el5_10.2
glib-1.2.10-20.el5
gtkglext-1.0.6-1.el5.rf
avahi-glib-0.6.16-10.el5_6
glib2-2.12.3-4.el5_3.1
compat-glibc-2.3.4-2.26
dbus-glib-devel-0.73-11.el5_9
xscreensaver-gl-extras-gss-5.04-1.el5.centos
glibc-headers-2.5-118.el5_10.2
glibc-utils-2.5-118.el5_10.2
libglade2-2.6.0-2
pygtk2-libglade-2.10.1-12.el5
freeglut-2.4.0-7.1.el5
dbus-glib-devel-0.73-11.el5_9
```

I believe I must be missing a library or something. Any ideas?

Comment: If I try to build OpenCV-2.4.5, I get the same error.

Comment: I was able to build it on CentOS 6.4. Must be something related to Centos 5.10...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *@florentbuisson* said earlier, your system might be missing `glx.h`. **But** it could also be including another `glx.h` before the Mesa version, one that doesn't define `glXGetProcAddressARB()`.

Either way, one quick hack to bypass this problem is to edit `/usr/local/src/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gl_core_3_1.cpp` and in the beginning of the file add:

```
#define glXGetProcAddress glXGetProcAddressARB
```

Comment: That suggestion got it past that error but now I have other compile errors I need to figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be missing GL/glx.h, perhaps with [mesa-libGL](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=/usr/include/GL/glx.h) ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to install the GTK+ OpenGL Extensions and their headers:

yum install libgtkglext1 libgtkglext1-dev

Comment: I don't see libgtkglext1 and libgtkglext1-dev in the CentOS repos. I did however install gtkglext and gtkglext-devel which I believe includes the GTK+ OpenGL extensions and headers.

Comment: This helped me find the right headers, thanks. (`sudo apt-get install libgtkglext1-dev libgtkgl2.0-dev` on my Ubuntu 14.04 system if anyone is wondering.)

Comment: Thanks, it help me to install on GtkGlExt for OpenCV on debian `apt-get install libgtkglext1 libgtkglext1-dev`

Comment: `sudo dnf install gtkglext-devel` on Fedora